# Keystone SSL config with intermediate CA cert

Tags: ssl-certificate, configuration-files, openstack, keystone

I'm trying to configure keystone with ssl certs from an intermediate CA.
Is there any way of getting keystone to "serve" the intermediate CA's cacert to clients?

I've tried setting it in keystone.conf with `ca_certs` option under both `[ssl]` and `[signing]` sections but some https clients (firefox, curl, wget & keystone-client) still do not trust the certs.

It works with Chrome(ium) and Opera tho.

NB. Running Keystone via Apache works but i'm looking for a standalone Keystone implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First -> [face palm]

It turns out you can just bundle the intermediate CA cert with your certificate and have keystone send that to the https client.

The Apache + mod_wsgi way is still better IMHO

Comment: I am facing issue with ssl config in keystone, when I enable [ssl] and [signing] option in keystone.conf file and if I restart keystone service, then it dies. Do I need to do any other config?